# How to type in the desired dimensions of a Frame tool object in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

As entitled ([Frame tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/photoshop/using/place-image-frame-tool.html) option (K), 6th down in lefthand menu, below Crop tool). I clearly see how to size a frame by dragging, but how can i set the dimension values of a frame by typing them in?

(I'm using v21.2.2.)

Comment: What frame? For what? Do you mean a rectangle? A selection? There's no "frame" tool anywhere that I know of. Has Adobe added one recently?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  What is "a frame object"?  There is nothing called that in Photoshop. Please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/140688/edit) and supply the missing information. Thanks.

Comment: I mean the Frame Tool (K), 6th down on left menu.

Comment: It's the Crop tool, not the "Frame tool".  There are instructions [here on the Adobe Help website](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/crop-straighten-photos.html#:~:text=%20How%20to%20crop%20and%20straighten%20photos%20,Photoshop%2C%20you%20may%20prefer%20using%20Content-Aware...%20More%20) on how to use the Crop tool.

Comment: No the one below the crop tool on my view is called the Frame View, I'm on v21.2.2.

Comment: It seems to be a new tool.  There's [a tutorial here on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02jgEnolazE) - looks like you can adjust it by typing the numbers in the properties panel.

Comment: Thanks @BillyKerr, you've answered to my question, can you submit as an answer and I'll accept it. (Unsure why someone has downvoted my question as it seems perfectly valid to me!)

Comment: Interesting. Appears to be wasted development. Another "feature" that is really so users don't have to learn anything in-depth. Looks simply like a layer mask, either linked or unlinked (double-clicking).

Comment: Ok, I've added an answer now.  @Scott - yes seems like a pointless addition to be honest.

Comment: @Scott, if I could upvote your last comment more than once I would.  New features like this confuse both beginners and experienced users. For different reasons. I would love to know if someone know what we can do with *Frames* that we couldn't do before.

Comment: @Wolff I gave up when they added the Bounding Box to Illustrator CS4 so that CorelDraw users felt more "at home". (AI Bounding box still has no unique function today and is still unnecessary.) This is just another example of Adobe bloating software rather than providing adequate user training regarding existing features. If there already exists 3 ways to accomplish something.. spending dev time to add a 4th is ridiculous in my opinion. Guess they have to justify the subscription in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Frame tool is a new tool introduced in CC 2019. I haven't updated my copy yet so I haven't really had the chance to test it yet.

Anyway, from a tutorial visible on youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02jgEnolazE), it looks like you can adjust the dimensions by typing values in the Properties Panel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

CTRL+T to Transform your layer, then you have the length and width on the top control bar.